# Pulling Value from Input Box on html page to insert into views.py function

Tags: python, django-views, django-forms, django-templates, django-database

there are similar questions to this, but I can't seem to figure this out. I have an input-box defined on my html page as this:

```
<input id="charge_input" name="charge_field" placeholder="Charge Name" style="padding: 10px;" />
```

With a button below to trigger the display function in views.

```
<button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" onclick="display()">SHOW DATA</button>
```

With an ajax call:

```
function display()
    {
        var charge_field = $('#charge_field').text()
        $.ajax(

            {
                url: 'display',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {"charge_field": charge_field},
                success: function(output) {

                    $('#Scrape_Display').text(output);
                    
                }
            }
        )
    }
```

My end goal, would be to use the value placed into the above input box, and use that value to filter in a one-to-many POSTGRES database. This is the function:

```
@csrf_exempt
def display(request):

   filtered_charges = request.POST.get('charge_field')
    
   listed_inmate=Inmate.objects.filter(Charges__chargess__icontains=filtered_charges)
   return render(request=request,
                  template_name='default.html',
                  context={'inmates': listed_inmates})
```

Here, Inmate the "one" table, and Charges is the "many" table. chargess is the column name of the table Charges. I hope this is clear, and any help would help! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here in your function, you need to change

`var charge_field = $('#charge_input').text()`

to

`var charge_field = $('#charge_input').val()`

EDIT: You're using `charge_field` as id instead of `charge_input` while grabbing the value.

Comment: Unfortunately, whenever I go to filter the table: "Charges" in views.py it is not recognizing the variable "filtered_charges" and is returning "None".

Comment: @ColeGulledge Check my edit, you should be using the ID instead of the name.

Comment: perfect! Thanks John! Great first contribution!